# How could I validate 13 digit phone number with hyphen?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a phone number formatted like this.+251-911-123456.

How could I create a regex that matches the given format.

I was trying to do it with the bellow given expression but it is not a success.

```
^(\+\d{1,2}\s)?\(?\d{3}\)?[\s.-]\d{3}[\s.-]\d{4}$
```

Comment: It is not a duplicate, Title might be the same but the question is different.

Comment: `(\+[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{6})` Will work

Comment: @Tom Powis. Many Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
/^\+\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{6}$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\+` - a `+` symbol
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{3}` - three digits
- `-` - a hyphen
- `\d{6}` - six digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/00KBnU/2) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5C%2B%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B3%7D-%5Cd%7B6%7D%24):

[image]

Comment: This is Awesome!!